Where is the Substitution Theorem used in the following example?
While going through the lecture notes on propositional logic, I came across the following example which proves that $(P \vee (Q \vee R) \wedge (R \vee \neg P)) \equiv R \vee (\neg P \wedge Q)$:
\begin{align*}
& (P \vee (Q \vee R)) \wedge (R \vee \neg P) \\& \equiv ((P \vee Q) \vee R) \wedge (R \vee \neg P) & \text{(Associativity and Substitution Theorem)} \\
& \equiv (R \vee (P \vee Q)) \wedge (R \vee \neg P) & \text{(Commutativity and Substitution Theorem)} \\
& \equiv R \vee ((P \vee Q) \wedge \neg P) & \text{(Distributivity)} \\
& \equiv R \vee (\neg P \wedge (P \vee Q)) & \text{(Commutativity and Substitution Theorem)} \\
& \equiv R \vee ((\neg P \wedge P) \vee (\neg P \wedge Q)) & \text{(Distributivity and Substitution Theorem)} \\
& \equiv R \vee (\text{false} \vee (\neg P \wedge Q)) & \text{(Complementation and Substitution Theorem)} \\
& \equiv R \vee (\neg P \wedge Q). & \text{(Identity Laws and Substitution Theorem)} 
\end{align*}
The question I have is that, after the first equivalence, how is the Substitution Theorem actually used?
To quote the Substitution Theorem from the lecture notes, it says that

Let $F_1, F_2, G_1, G_2$ be formulas, and $P$ a propositional variable. If $F_1 \equiv F_2$ and $G_1 \equiv G_2$, then $G_1[F_1/P] = G_2[F_2/P]$.

But in the first line, where it says Associativity and Substitution Theorem are both used, what are the $F_1, F_2, G_1, G_2$ specifically? And which $P$ was substituted?

Associativity implies that
$$\underbrace{P \lor (Q \lor R)}_{F_1} \equiv \underbrace{(P \lor Q) \lor R}_{F_2}.$$
Obviously we have
$$\underbrace{P' \land (R \lor \neg P)}_{G_1} \equiv \underbrace{P' \land (R \lor \neg P)}_{G_2}$$
for any $P'$, it follows from substitution that
$$(P \lor (Q \lor R)) \land (R \lor \neg P) = G_1[F_1/P'] \equiv G_2[F_2/P'] = ((P \lor Q) \lor R) \land (R \lor \neg P).$$

As a bit of context, technically, when you work with equalities involving numbers you're doing the same thing.
For example to show that $2 \cdot 5 + 1 = 5 \cdot 2 + 1$ you use commutativity to get $2 \cdot 5 = 5 \cdot 2$ and identity to get something like $x + 1 = x + 1$, and then substitute $x$ for $2 \cdot 5$ and $5 \cdot 2$ respectively.
Equivalence relations that allow these kinds of substitution, like $\equiv$, are called congruence relation.

Oh now it's so clear. So the statement of the substitution theorem I quoted from the lecture notes is actually incomplete, right? Judging from your answer, it seems that we can not only substitute propositional variables with formulas, but also formulas with formulas. Please correct my understanding if it's wrong.

Because in the explanation you gave, $P'$ doesn't seem to qualify as a propositional variable. It appears to be a formula to me.

Yes, I didn't read your quotation carefully enough
Removed the part that referred to $P'$ as a formula.

Sorry, what I wrote was not correct.
You can generalize to subformulas if $G_1 = G_2$, but not in general.

Ok. Now I think I understand it. Thanks for the response.
